# Responsive form, response to Gmail

Tags: javascript, html, css

Today I tried to create a form using html, css and js which will send the response to the entered mail ID in the codes...but as I ran the code the response isn't going on the mail after clicking on the Submit button.
Here is the code which I tried with:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>codeG</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">

<form onsubmit="sendEmail(); reset(); return false;">

<h3> LOGIN FORM <hr width="50px" style="background: #555; height:5px"></h3>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Valid Email" required>
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Valid Phone no." required>
<textarea id="message" rows="4" placeholder="Leave a comment..."></textarea>
<button type="Submit"> Submit </button>

</form>

    </div>
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js">
</script>
   <script>
    function sendEmail(){
    Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.gmail.com",
    Username : "ayushbharti.official123@gmail.com",
    Password : "*********",
    To : 'ayushbharti.official123@gmail.com',
    From : document.getElementById("email").value,
    Subject : "New Contact Form Equiry",
    Body : "Name: " + document.getElementById("name").value
    + "<br> Email:" + document.getElementById("eamil").value
    + "<br> Phone no.:" + document.getElementById("phone").value
    + "<br> Message:" + document.getElementById("message").value
}).then(
  message => alert("Message Sent Successfully")
);
    }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Please do try to fix my issue on mentioned path

Comment: Is the console or the networking tab show anything? In my opinion, you should call the reset function in your `then` callback

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. **Read the error messages**. You made a typo. `eamil` does not match `email`. (Voting to close the question because it was caused by a typo)

Comment: Note that GMail upped their security recently so may not be compatible with smtp.js anymore any way.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an issue in your `form` tag.
*let me describe*

```js
function sendEmail() {
  Email.send({
    Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    Username: "ayushbharti.official123@gmail.com",
    Password: "*********",
    To: 'ayushbharti.official123@gmail.com',
    From: document.getElementById("email").value,
    Subject: "New Contact Form Equiry",
    Body: "Name: " + document.getElementById("name").value +
      "<br> Email:" + document.getElementById("eamil").value +
      "<br> Phone no.:" + document.getElementById("phone").value +
      "<br> Message:" + document.getElementById("message").value
  }).then(
    message => alert("Message Sent Successfully")
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--first disable default action of the form -->
  <form onsubmit="return false;sendEmail(); reset();">

    <h3> LOGIN FORM
      <hr width="50px" style="background: #555; height:5px">
    </h3>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Valid Email" required>
    <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Valid Phone no." required>
    <textarea id="message" rows="4" placeholder="Leave a comment..."></textarea>
    <button type="Submit"> Submit </button>

  </form>

</div>
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js">
</script>
```

Comment: `<!--first disable default action of the form -->` — If you `return false` as the **first** thing the `onsubmit` function does then you **prevent the rest of the function running entirely**. You haven't fixed the problem but you've created an extra one.